# When saving data to server is working for @GetMapping instead of @PostMapping

Tags: css, spring, http, view, model

I am new to Spring Boot and to web applications, in general. I was facing an issue with my saveStudent() method

```
@PostMapping("/students")
public ModelAndView saveStudent(Student student) {
    repo.save(student);
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    mv.addObject("obj",student);
    mv.setViewName("addStudent");
    return mv;
}
```

I know that if I am saving data to server HTTP uses POST method, but when retrieving data it uses GET method. In this case, since I am saving a Student instance to database, I should use PostMapping right? But to my surprise this method works if I change annotation to @GetMapping, can you please explain why?

```
@GetMapping("/students")
public ModelAndView saveStudent(Student student) {
    repo.save(student);
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    mv.addObject("obj",student);
    mv.setViewName("addStudent");
    return mv;
}
```

This method works fine and PostMapping does not work. But why?

MainController

```
package com.firstdbproj.demo.controller;


import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.firstdbproj.demo.Student;
import com.firstdbproj.demo.dao.StudentRepo;


@RestController
public class MainController {

    @Autowired
    StudentRepo repo;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView showIndexPage() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.setViewName("index");
        return mv;
    }

    @PostMapping("/students")
    public ModelAndView fetchStudent(Student student) {
        repo.save(student);
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.addObject("obj",student);
        mv.setViewName("addStudent");
        return mv;
    }


    @GetMapping(path="/students/{id}")
    @ResponseBody
    public Optional<Student> showStudentinJSON(@PathVariable("id")int ids) {
        Optional<Student> obj = repo.findById(ids);
        return obj;
    }


    @RequestMapping("/showStudentUsingId")
    public ModelAndView showStudent(@RequestParam("id")int ids) {
        Student obj = repo.findById(ids).orElse(new Student(0,"null"));
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.addObject("student",obj);
        mv.setViewName("showStudent");
        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/showStudentUsingName")
    public ModelAndView showStudent(@RequestParam("id")String name) {
        Student obj = repo.findByName(name);
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.addObject("student",obj);
        mv.setViewName("showStudent");
        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/showAllStudent")
    public String showAllStudent() {
        List<Student> obj = (List<Student>) repo.findAllSorted();
        return obj.toString();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/showAllStudentWhereName")
    public String showAllStudentWhereName(@RequestParam("id")String name) {
        List<Student> obj = (List<Student>) repo.findAllWhereName(name);
        return obj.toString();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/getStudent")
    public ModelAndView getStudent() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.setViewName("getStudent");
        return mv;
    }

}
```

Student Repo

```
package com.firstdbproj.demo;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Entity
public class Student {

    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Student(){

    }
    public Student(int id,String name){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }
}
```

addStudent.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" isELIgnored="false"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    Hello ${obj.id}, ${obj.name}!
    <form action="/">
    <input type="submit" value="Add another Record!">
    <input type="submit" formaction="getStudent" value="Fetch Records!">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have already done this. Please rebuild and restart the server. That can help!!

Comment: But if they are not mandatory, then using @PostMapping should have worked, but instead it gives an exception showing, "There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405). Request method 'GET' not supported"

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding the whole concepts and purpose of REST. HTTP methods are suggestions, not restriction.

It's recommended to use `GET` to retrieve data but it's not mandatory. By using `GET` you get the additional benefit of browser caching but you can use POST/PUT just the same. Because HTTP methods are suggestions/hints to what your API does, that's why your controllers work.

Example:

```
GET /students <--- implies that this API will return a list of student
POST /students <--- implies that this API will create a student
```

HTTP methods serves as a hint to what your API does, but you can create a student using `GET` instead of `POST` just the same. Technically doable but you'll be going against the convention

A bit of reading material: https://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html

### Edit to answer question in comment

If you're getting a 405, it means that methods is not supported for a particular resource path. For example, let's say you have this

```java
@PostMapping("/students")
public String createStudent() {
   // logic
}

@GetMapping("/students") 
public List<String> getListOfStudents() {
  //logic
}
```

Then both `POST` and `GET` request to `/students` will work and you won't get 405. However, if you decide to send `DELETE`, `PUT` to `/students`, you will get 405. So in your case you're probably missing correct annotation to the correct resource

Comment: But if they are not mandatory, then using @PostMapping should have worked, but instead it gives an exception showing, 
  "There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Request method 'GET' not supported"